# <p:calendar> don't popup anymore after adding pattern attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to make a calander with PrimeFaces.

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}"  />
```

It works good. However, when I modify it to

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

then the popup calander don't appear.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: @Masus: hint for future opaque questions like that, click "edit" link. You'll more than often see that the user didn't understood the message formatting rules and/or didn't carefully paid attention to message preview. The code is then hidden in the message source. Just fix that accordingly with proper formatting so that the code reappaears.

Comment: Works for me. What version of PF are you running?

Comment: sorry 
what I mean exactly that I can get calendar at the first sample but when I want it with time means hour munite and second I can't see it it didnt appear any calender 
the prob was due to jquery library when I move the jq lib it works